# How can I connect Backstage.io to PyPI server?

Tags: python, pypiserver

I'm trying to spin up a PyPI server on the company I work for, for the purposes of sharing Python packages and libraries in a more reliable way.

Also we are trying to implement Backstage.io as our one stop shop for components and things related to inner-source.

Is there a way to connect those two things? Or is there any plug-in already in place to do that connection?

So far we are at research phase, so nothing was attempted yet. But we expect that the connection is possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.